# Robotium AssertionFailedError: Click can not be completed

Tags: android, robotium

I have been getting "Click can not be completed" error when running my tests but it happens intermittently.

Before calling clickOnView, I make sure that the view is not null.

Is there anything else that I need to check on before calling clickOnView?

```
Button btnLike = (Button) vwItem.findViewById(R.id.buttonLike);
assertTrue(solo.waitForCondition(new Common.WaitUntilViewNotNull(solo, vwItem, R.id.buttonLike), 5000));
solo.clickOnView(btnLike);

public static class WaitUntilViewNotNull implements Condition {
    int viewId;
    Solo solo;
    View parentView;

    public WaitUntilViewNotNull(Solo solo, View parentView, int viewId) {
        this.solo = solo;
        this.viewId = viewId;
        this.parentView = parentView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSatisfied() {

        View v = null;
        if (parentView != null) {
            v = (View)parentView.findViewById(viewId);

        }
        else {
            v = (View) solo.getView(viewId);
        }

        return v != null;
    }

}
```

Comment: You are not really checking it.
Change: solo.waitForCondition... to assertTrue(solo.waitForCondition...

Comment: I just tried that but didn't make a difference. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Please check this: http://wklej.org/hash/e757bfe69e8/
before clicking and show the result.

Comment: Appreciate the help maszter. Here's what I got: D/TimelineTest(14480): X: 0  
 Y: 0  
 W: 720  
 H: 1280

Comment: Btw, I'm clicking "Like" inside a ListView.

Comment: Please check those as well:
http://wklej.org/hash/5fa7c4cc464/
When it's failing, is this button fully visible on the screen?

Comment: Which one should I check? the ListView? I grab the 1st item on the list & click on the Like button inside the item.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that problem is in assigning `btnLike` variable before view is rendered. Therefore it equals `null`.

BTW, probably you'd prefer `waitForView` instead of custom `Condition`.

```
assertTrue(solo.waitForView(R.id.buttonLike, 1, 5000));
Button btnLike = (Button) vwItem.findViewById(R.id.buttonLike);
solo.clickOnView(btnLike);
```